# Dropdown menu overlapping it's container inside flexbox

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, flexbox

I'm working on my personal site. The parent header is placed in a flexbox:

HTML:

```
<header class="main">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#"><img src="image.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navigation">
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Sub-Menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
header { display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; justify-content: center; overflow: auto;
         height: 20vh; width: 100%; align-items: flex-end; z-index: 999; }

header .content { width: 50vw; height: auto; position: relative;
                  display: -webkit-inline-flex; display: inline-flex;
                  justify-content: space-between; overflow: auto; align-items: flex-end; }
```

This will place the logo and the nav on the bottom of the parent, at the left and right side of these elements in the `header .content` div.

However my dropdown menu items overlapping the container, causing a vertical scrollbar in the header.

I don't want to use `position: absolute;` on the nav and logo instead of flexbox, because that way they can overlap each other horizontally. Writing a nav hider for little width screens will solve this, but I think flexbox is a much nicer solution.

For the full dropdown menu css please visit the JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/s4Lqqyyp/15/

Is there any way to use flexbox as a parent and having dropdown menu items hidden with this?

```
.main-nav ul ul { visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; position: absolute; }
```

Thank You for your help!

Update:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/s4Lqqyyp/18/

Adding `.container { display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; flex-direction: column; }` and removing `position: relative;` from `header .content` seems like fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since youre working with flexbox, remove the flex divs width/height values (like `height: 20vh`) and use the [**flex property**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp) instead. Example: `flex: 0 0 auto`. Another common flex property is the [**flex direction**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp) used to set the divs direction (column or row) inside a container. Sometimes [**flex wrap**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp) is also necessary. Take a look in these 3 properties and I'm sure you'll get rid of these undesired scrolls.

Three flex properties important to align: [**Align items**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp) to vertical align. [**Justify content**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_justify-content.asp) to horizontal align. [**Align content**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-content.asp) for items on multi-lines inside a container.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100vh;  
  margin: 0;
}

#container { 
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column; /* Safari 6.1+ */
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#A {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 20%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 20%;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  height: 20%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari 6.1+ */
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-end; /* Safari 7.0+ */
  align-items: flex-end;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#B {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 60%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 60%;
  flex: 0 0 60%;
  height: 60%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap; /* Safari 6.1+ */
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari 6.1+ */
  flex-direction: row;
}

#C {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 20%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 20%;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row; /* Safari 6.1+ */
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-align-items: flex-start; /* Safari 7.0+ */
  align-items: flex-start;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#header {
 -webkit-flex: 0 0 80%;
 -ms-flex: 0 0 80%;
 flex: 0 0 80%;
 text-align: center;
 height: 80%;
}

#footer {
 -webkit-flex: 0 0 80%;
 -ms-flex: 0 0 80%;
 flex: 0 0 80%;
 text-align: center;
}

#B img {  
  height: 100%; 
}

#logo {
  height: calc(100% - 10px);
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;  
}

span {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#header span {  
  vertical-align: super;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id=A style="background-color:hotpink;">
<div id=header style="background-color:honeydew;"><span>MENU 1 - MENU 2</span><img src="http://lantosistvan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/lantosistvan-logo-100px-003.png" alt="Lantos István Photography" id=logo /><span>MENU 3 - MENU 4</span></div>
</div>
  
<div id=B style="background-color:honeydew;">  
<img src="http://lantosistvan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/20140516-eskuvo-barbi-balazs-0001-1400px.jpg" alt="">    
<img src="http://lantosistvan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/20140516-eskuvo-barbi-balazs-0002-1400px.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://lantosistvan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/20140516-eskuvo-barbi-balazs-0003-1400px.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://lantosistvan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/20140516-eskuvo-barbi-balazs-0004-1400px.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://lantosistvan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/20140516-eskuvo-barbi-balazs-0006-1400px.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://lantosistvan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/20140516-eskuvo-barbi-balazs-0007-1400px.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://lantosistvan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/20140516-eskuvo-barbi-balazs-0008-1400px.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://lantosistvan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/20140516-eskuvo-barbi-balazs-0009-1400px.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://lantosistvan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/20140516-eskuvo-barbi-balazs-0011-1400px.jpg" alt="">
<img src="http://lantosistvan.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/20140516-eskuvo-barbi-balazs-0012-1400px.jpg" alt="">
</div>
  
<div id=C style="background-color:hotpink;">
<div id=footer style="background-color:honeydew;"><span>FOOTER</span></div>  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank You! I will try this today.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/s4Lqqyyp/18/
Adding `.container { display: -webkit-flex; display: flex; flex-direction: column; }` and removing `position: relative;` from `header .content` seems like fixed the issue. Thank You!

Comment: Now its a trully flex layout. Great (:

Comment: Not yet, but I try to understand this new method. :)

Comment: Now its a trully flex header*. Great (:

Comment: Right now I use vh and vw to define my header's height and width. I try to use the `flex: 0 0 20vh` method that you recommended, but I have hard time with it. Plus although this way the logo and nav is relative to each other, not absolute positioned, but the logo still overlapping to the top in small screen. So there's a lot of work still. :) I want fix pixel size for logo, but it would be nice of it reaches the top of the screen, it will start to push down every other content, including images and the footer. Or the other option, it will start to become smaller.

Comment: BTW positioning with flexbox totally feels like flexbox IS a CSS framework. Able to positioning content at every corner / center of a box, align, justify wherever you want, feels like working with bootstrap.

Comment: if you check the .css of the frameworks like bootstrap you'll notice flex being largely used (because it works great on responsive design).

Comment: Wow, really nice solution! Thanks! :)

Comment: I limited the Logo's height this way to not overflow it's parent flexbox. So far not perfect, but at least it's not overflowing to the top: https://jsfiddle.net/Lanti/s4Lqqyyp/39/
`.logo { max-width: 15vh; min-width: 10vh; } .logo a img { width: 100%; height: 100%; }` Unfortunately I cannot set `body, html`'s height to `100vh`, because although the header, horizontal gallery and the footer centered on the viewport, but maybe I want to add another divs below that, like in this JSfiddle.

Comment: a small tip: on your menu items, use `margin-left: 10px;` instead of `margin-right: 10px;` to have this: [**link1**](https://i.gyazo.com/72095c7ecf3521719d9b9f3ba06473ed.png) instead of this: [**link2**](https://i.gyazo.com/95f6c024c7af343e1248ec349f83005a.png)

Comment: Thank You! I modified it! :)