# How to position submenus in a drop-down-menu using flexbox

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to program a dropdown-menu. The code I am using is only css and I use flexbox to make the drop-down-menu.
However, my problem is to position my sub-menus that they are directly under my main menu. How can I do that?

I've looked for an answer but I didn't found a thread, that describes exactly my problem.

[Dropdown menu overlapping it's container inside flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773346/dropdown-menu-overlapping-its-container-inside-flexbox)

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content {
  margin: 0 15%;
}


/* ########################################################################## */


/*  Dropdownmenu */


/*  ########################################################################## */

nav {
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

nav>ul li {
  padding: 10px;
}

nav>ul>li>ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

.align-menu-right {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.active {
  background-color: #999;
}

.current-menu>a {
  color: #E95D0F;
}

nav>ul>li:hover ul>li {
  display: block;
}

nav>ul>li:hover,
nav>ul>li>ul li:hover {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

nav>ul>li:hover>a,
nav>ul>li>ul li:hover>a {
  color: #FFF;
}

.current-menu:hover>a {
  color: #E95D0F;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dropdownmenü</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="content">

    <!-- ########################################################################## -->
    <!--  Dropdownmenu -->
    <!--  ########################################################################## -->

    <div class="nav-container">
      <nav>
        <ul class="flex-container">

          <li class="current-menu"><a href="#">Menü 1</a>
            <ul>
              <li class="current-menu"><a href="#">Untermenü 1-1</li></a>
                <li><a href="#">Untermenü 1-2</li></a>
                  <li><a href="#">Untermenü 1-3</li></a>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Menü 2</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Untermenü 2-1</li></a>
                  <li><a href="#">Untermenü 2-2</li></a>
                    <li><a href="#">Untermenü 2-3</li></a>
              </ul>
              </li>

              <li class="align-menu-right"><a href="#">Menü 3</a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Untermenü 3-1</li></a>
                    <li><a href="#">Untermenü 3-2</li></a>
                      <li><a href="#">Untermenü 3-3</li></a>
                </ul>
                </li>

                <li><a href="#">Menü 4</a>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Untermenü 4-1</li></a>
                      <li><a href="#">Untermenü 4-2</li></a>
                        <li><a href="#">Untermenü 4-3</li></a>
                  </ul>
                  </li>

        </ul>
      </nav>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is setting `padding:10px` for all `<ul>` and `<li>`.

```
nav > ul li{
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Try to separate them with different classes then do the styling. In my example below, I've added `.li-padding` class in order to style differently.

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content{
  margin: 0 15%;
}

/* ########################################################################## */
/*  Dropdownmenu */
/*  ########################################################################## */

nav{
  background-color: #F0F0F0;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
}

nav ul{
  display: flex;
}

nav > ul{
  padding: 10px;
}

   .li-padding{
  padding-right:10px
}

nav > ul > li > ul{
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav ul li ul li{
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: none;
}

.align-menu-right{
  margin-left: auto;
}

.active{
  background-color: #999;
}

.current-menu > a{
  color:#E95D0F;
}

nav > ul >li:hover ul > li{
  display: block;
}

nav > ul > li:hover, nav > ul > li > ul li:hover{
  background-color: #CCC;
}

nav > ul > li:hover > a, nav > ul > li > ul li:hover > a{
  color: #FFF;
}

.current-menu:hover > a{
  color:#E95D0F;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Dropdownmenü</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/css/styles.css">
 </head>
 <body>

    <div class="content">

   <!-- ########################################################################## -->
   <!--  Dropdownmenu -->
   <!--  ########################################################################## -->

      <div class="nav-container">
    <nav>
         <ul class="flex-container">

           <li class="current-menu li-padding"><a href="#" >Menü 1</a>
             <ul>
               <li class="current-menu"><a href="#">Untermenü 1-1</li></a>
               <li><a href="#">Untermenü 1-2</li></a>
               <li><a href="#">Untermenü 1-3</li></a>
             </ul>
           </li>

           <li><a href="#">Menü 2</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Untermenü 2-1</li></a>
               <li><a href="#">Untermenü 2-2</li></a>
               <li><a href="#">Untermenü 2-3</li></a>
             </ul>
           </li>

           <li class="align-menu-right li-padding"><a href="#">Menü 3</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Untermenü 3-1</li></a>
               <li><a href="#">Untermenü 3-2</li></a>
               <li><a href="#">Untermenü 3-3</li></a>
             </ul>
           </li>

      <li><a href="#">Menü 4</a>
             <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Untermenü 4-1</li></a>
               <li><a href="#">Untermenü 4-2</li></a>
               <li><a href="#">Untermenü 4-3</li></a>
             </ul>
           </li>

     </ul>
   </nav>

      </div>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. One problem is solved. But there is still the problem that Untermenü 1-1, Untermenü 2-1, Untermenü 3-1 and Untermenü 4-1 must be further down.

Comment: sorry but i'm not sure what u mean "further down" ?

Comment: If you hover on the main-menu. Then the first sub-menu-item should be further down. For example Untermenü 1-1 should be exactly under the navbar.

Comment: Maybe adding `padding-top:10px` in `nav ul li ul li` is what u need but i'm still not so sure. Just check my updated answer