# Issue with... Stuff Html CSS

Tags: html, css

[dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xrsk.png)

Here is the image of the "dashboard I am making."

As you can see the menu is behind a div, and I've worked with the z-index so the dropdown menu's is greater, but it isn't working. Here is the code for both elements:

Dropdown:

```css
.home-container3 {
  top: 158px;
  right: 10%;
  width: 630px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #313131;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Div:

```
.home-container3 {
  top: 158px;
  right: 10%;
  width: 630px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #313131;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

There is also another issue with a button i added (and here is the ENTIRE HTML, just to see if there is any formatting errors:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <style>
      html {  line-height: 1.15;}body {  margin: 0;}* {  box-sizing: border-box;  border-width: 0;  border-style: solid;}p,li,ul,pre,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {  margin: 0;  padding: 0;}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea {  font-family: inherit;  font-size: 100%;  line-height: 1.15;  margin: 0;}button,select {  text-transform: none;}button,[type="button"],[type="reset"],[type="submit"] {  -webkit-appearance: button;}button::-moz-focus-inner,[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {  border-style: none;  padding: 0;}button:-moz-focus,[type="button"]:-moz-focus,[type="reset"]:-moz-focus,[type="submit"]:-moz-focus {  outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;}a {  color: inherit;  text-decoration: inherit;}input {  padding: 2px 4px;}img {  display: block;}
    </style>
    <style>
      html {
        font-family: Inter;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      body {
        font-weight: 400;
        font-style:normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: none;
        letter-spacing: normal;
        line-height: 1.15;
        color: var(--dl-color-gray-black);
        background-color: var(--dl-color-gray-white);

      }
    </style>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">  
      function doChange() {  
          var myInput = document.getElementById('prefixInput').value;  
          document.getElementById('update').innerHTML = myInput;  
      }  

      function menuToggle() {
    const toggleMenu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    toggleMenu.classList.toggle('active')
}
  </script>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <link href="./home.css" rel="stylesheet" />

      <div class="home-container">
        <header data-role="Header" class="home-header">
          <div class="home-container1">
            <img
              alt="logo"
              src="public/playground_assets/elixre-text%201-1500h.png"
              class="home-image"
            />
            <div class="home-nav">
              <nav
                class="navigation-links-nav navigation-links-root-class-name12"
              >
                <span class="navigation-links-text">
                  <span>My Servers</span>
                </span>
                <span class="navigation-links-text1"><span>Discord</span></span>
                <span class="navigation-links-text2"><span>Docs</span></span>
                <span class="navigation-links-text3">
                  <span>Invite Elixre</span>
                </span>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div data-type="BurgerMenu" class="home-burger-menu">
            <svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" class="home-icon">
              <path
                d="M128 554.667h768c23.552 0 42.667-19.115 42.667-42.667s-19.115-42.667-42.667-42.667h-768c-23.552 0-42.667 19.115-42.667 42.667s19.115 42.667 42.667 42.667zM128 298.667h768c23.552 0 42.667-19.115 42.667-42.667s-19.115-42.667-42.667-42.667h-768c-23.552 0-42.667 19.115-42.667 42.667s19.115 42.667 42.667 42.667zM128 810.667h768c23.552 0 42.667-19.115 42.667-42.667s-19.115-42.667-42.667-42.667h-768c-23.552 0-42.667 19.115-42.667 42.667s19.115 42.667 42.667 42.667z"
              ></path>
            </svg>
          </div>
          <div data-type="MobileMenu" class="home-mobile-menu">
            <nav class="home-nav1">
              <div class="home-container2">
                <img
                  alt="image"
                  src="https://presentation-website-assets.teleporthq.io/logos/logo.png"
                  class="home-image1"
                />
                <div data-type="CloseMobileMenu" class="home-close-mobile-menu">
                  <svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" class="home-icon02">
                    <path
                      d="M810 274l-238 238 238 238-60 60-238-238-238 238-60-60 238-238-238-238 60-60 238 238 238-238z"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
              <nav
                class="navigation-links-nav navigation-links-root-class-name14"
              >
                <span class="navigation-links-text">
                  <span>My Servers</span>
                </span>
                <span class="navigation-links-text1"><span>Discord</span></span>
                <span class="navigation-links-text2"><span>Docs</span></span>
                <span class="navigation-links-text3">
                  <span>Invite Elixre</span>
                </span>
              </nav>
            </nav>
            <div>
              <svg viewBox="0 0 950.8571428571428 1024" class="home-icon04">
                <path
                  d="M925.714 233.143c-25.143 36.571-56.571 69.143-92.571 95.429 0.571 8 0.571 16 0.571 24 0 244-185.714 525.143-525.143 525.143-104.571 0-201.714-30.286-283.429-82.857 14.857 1.714 29.143 2.286 44.571 2.286 86.286 0 165.714-29.143 229.143-78.857-81.143-1.714-149.143-54.857-172.571-128 11.429 1.714 22.857 2.857 34.857 2.857 16.571 0 33.143-2.286 48.571-6.286-84.571-17.143-148-91.429-148-181.143v-2.286c24.571 13.714 53.143 22.286 83.429 23.429-49.714-33.143-82.286-89.714-82.286-153.714 0-34.286 9.143-65.714 25.143-93.143 90.857 112 227.429 185.143 380.571 193.143-2.857-13.714-4.571-28-4.571-42.286 0-101.714 82.286-184.571 184.571-184.571 53.143 0 101.143 22.286 134.857 58.286 41.714-8 81.714-23.429 117.143-44.571-13.714 42.857-42.857 78.857-81.143 101.714 37.143-4 73.143-14.286 106.286-28.571z"
                ></path><svg
              /><svg viewBox="0 0 877.7142857142857 1024" class="home-icon06">
                <path
                  d="M585.143 512c0-80.571-65.714-146.286-146.286-146.286s-146.286 65.714-146.286 146.286 65.714 146.286 146.286 146.286 146.286-65.714 146.286-146.286zM664 512c0 124.571-100.571 225.143-225.143 225.143s-225.143-100.571-225.143-225.143 100.571-225.143 225.143-225.143 225.143 100.571 225.143 225.143zM725.714 277.714c0 29.143-23.429 52.571-52.571 52.571s-52.571-23.429-52.571-52.571 23.429-52.571 52.571-52.571 52.571 23.429 52.571 52.571zM438.857 152c-64 0-201.143-5.143-258.857 17.714-20 8-34.857 17.714-50.286 33.143s-25.143 30.286-33.143 50.286c-22.857 57.714-17.714 194.857-17.714 258.857s-5.143 201.143 17.714 258.857c8 20 17.714 34.857 33.143 50.286s30.286 25.143 50.286 33.143c57.714 22.857 194.857 17.714 258.857 17.714s201.143 5.143 258.857-17.714c20-8 34.857-17.714 50.286-33.143s25.143-30.286 33.143-50.286c22.857-57.714 17.714-194.857 17.714-258.857s5.143-201.143-17.714-258.857c-8-20-17.714-34.857-33.143-50.286s-30.286-25.143-50.286-33.143c-57.714-22.857-194.857-17.714-258.857-17.714zM877.714 512c0 60.571 0.571 120.571-2.857 181.143-3.429 70.286-19.429 132.571-70.857 184s-113.714 67.429-184 70.857c-60.571 3.429-120.571 2.857-181.143 2.857s-120.571 0.571-181.143-2.857c-70.286-3.429-132.571-19.429-184-70.857s-67.429-113.714-70.857-184c-3.429-60.571-2.857-120.571-2.857-181.143s-0.571-120.571 2.857-181.143c3.429-70.286 19.429-132.571 70.857-184s113.714-67.429 184-70.857c60.571-3.429 120.571-2.857 181.143-2.857s120.571-0.571 181.143 2.857c70.286 3.429 132.571 19.429 184 70.857s67.429 113.714 70.857 184c3.429 60.571 2.857 120.571 2.857 181.143z"
                ></path></svg
              ><svg viewBox="0 0 602.2582857142856 1024" class="home-icon08">
                <path
                  d="M548 6.857v150.857h-89.714c-70.286 0-83.429 33.714-83.429 82.286v108h167.429l-22.286 169.143h-145.143v433.714h-174.857v-433.714h-145.714v-169.143h145.714v-124.571c0-144.571 88.571-223.429 217.714-223.429 61.714 0 114.857 4.571 130.286 6.857z"
                ></path>
              </svg>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="action">
            <div class="text"><h3>Username Example#tag</h3></div>
            <div class="profile">
              <img src="./img/nerd.png" alt="" />
            </div>
            <span class="menuicon" onclick="menuToggle();"
              ><i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i
            ></span>
            <div class="menu">
              <h3>Username<br /></h3>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Payments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </header>
        <div class="home-container3 div">
          <span class="home-text">
            <span class="home-text01">Customize</span>
            <span class="home-text02">Prefix</span>
          </span>
          <span class="home-text03">
            <span class="home-text04">Current Prefix:</span>
            <span id= "update" class="home-text05">&#123;&#123;Prefix&#125;&#125;</span>
          </span>
          <span class="home-text06">
            <span class="home-text07">Enabled Plugins:</span>
            <br />
            <span class="home-text09">
              Utility Commands, Toxicity Filter, Automod, Dynamic Nametags,
              Ticketing, Welcomer, Giveaways, Ticketing, Bad Word Prevention,
              Social Media Announcements
            </span>
          </span>
          <span class="home-text10">
            <span class="home-text11">Info For</span>
            <span id="update" class="home-text12">&#123;&#123;server&#125;&#125;</span>
          </span>
          <input
            id="prefixInput"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Prefix"
            class="home-textinput input"
            required
            maxlength="10"
          />
          <input
            type="button"
            value="Save"
            placeholder="placeholder"
            class="home-textinput1 input"
            onclick='doChange()'
          />
          <button class="home-button button">
            <span class="home-text13">Customize Plugins</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <span class="home-text14">
          <span class="home-text15">My</span>
          <span class="home-text16">Servers</span>
        </span>
        <button type="button" class="select-server">
          <span class="button__image"
            ><img src="./img/Elixre-Bot.png" class="Select-Image"
          /></span>
          <span class="button__text">[Server]</span>
          <span class="button__icon"
            ><i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i
          ></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the specific part that isn't showing up is:

```html
<button type="button" class="select-server">
          <span class="button__image"
            ><img src="./img/Elixre-Bot.png" class="Select-Image"
          /></span>
          <span class="button__text">[Server]</span>
          <span class="button__icon"
            ><i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i
          ></span>
        </button>
```

Here is the CSS for the button:

```css
.select-server {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgb(83, 83, 83);
  border-radius: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 550;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: relative;
  top: 115px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(83, 83, 83);
  left: -34%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.button__text,
.button__image,
.button__icon {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 8px;
  color: white;
  height: 100%;
}

img.Select-Image {
  width: 40px;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.button__icon {
  margin-right: 12px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 40px;
}

.select-server:hover {
  background-color: black;
  border: 2px solid black;
  transition: .5s;
}

.select-server:focus {
  border: 2px solid #21ff46;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

I know it's a lot to take in, but hopefully someone can help

Comment: What exactly is your problem that you're having? You have also messed up the code on the post. You put CSS in HTML, and HTML in CSS in the preview system.

Comment: The problem is that the dropdown is behind a div and a button is not showing

Comment: And I hopefully fixed the HTML and CSS in the wrong areas

Comment: You haven't. You separated them which is worse.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add z-index higher to .menu

```
.menu{
 z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: And no that did not work

Comment: try this, they have similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773346/dropdown-menu-overlapping-its-container-inside-flexbox

Comment: Not sure what that means, or what I should do. What exactly are you saying?